# In what file do I put the installation steps in my git repository?

Tags: git, documentation, gitlab

I have a git repository and I would like to add the installation steps required to make the project work locally. The project is a company and private project and users will also be contributors. I'm using GitLab.

But I don't know in what file to write these steps. I have several options in mind such as:

- the `README.md` file: it's the default page that users and contributors will see. But I fear too much information inside one file will make it hard to read.
- the `CONTRIBUTING.md` file: in my case, people who will install the project will be contributors. If they want to contribute, they will need to install the project locally..
- an `INSTALL.md` file: it's not recognized by GitLab as `CONTRIBUTING` and `README` are. But it's far more obvious in the name that it contains the installation steps.

What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: You could split it up into folders with a README.md per folder, and link to the various sections. I'm not on a computer that I can check, but if you navigate to a .MD file directly in GitLab, does it not show the formatted Markdown?

Comment: Yes, it does show the formatted markdown when you go on .md file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like seeing `INSTALL.md` in a project. If I'm wondering "how do I install this?" then INSTALL.md is an obvious place to look.

In README.md add a small section about installation, and basically point people to the INSTALL.md file hosted in GitLab:

> ### About Project
>
> ...
>
> ### Contributing
>
> ..
>
> ### Installation Instructions
>
> See [INSTALL.md](http://example.com/path/to/your/repo/INSTALL.md) for full instructions.

This gives you the best of both worlds. You get an appropriately named file and a link from the README file rendered in GitLab to the appropriately named file.

In fact this would work for GitHub, Azure DevOps or any other git hosting solution that does something special with the README file.

Comment: The link doesn't need to point specificly to the file hosted at gitlab - you can write a relative link to point to the file hosted next to the readme, or on a local workstation: `[INSTALL.md](INSTALL.md)`

Comment: Coming back late to accept this answer: this is what I enforced on all the repositories I manage :)